# How to have quotes separated values in a Rails CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

My CSV is exporting as :

```
"user_name,course_code,completion_date,completion_status,score"
621,BTB,2014/4/22,complete,100
```

But I want it like :

```
"user_name","course_code","completion_date","completion_status","score"
"621","BTB","2014/4/22","complete","100"
```

The code that generates my export is :

```
  csv << ["user_name,course_code,completion_date,completion_status,score"]
  @completes.each do |quiz|
    csv << [member.id.to_s, apply_course_code(@section), quiz.updated_at.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d'), 'complete', '100']
  end
```

How can I generate quotes separated values in my CSV?

Comment: Those aren't "quote separated values". They're quoted comma-separated values, which is what CSV will do if there is an embedded space or comma in a field, and isn't necessary as a field by nature is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an option `force_quotes: true` to wrap every entry with quotes. But in your header you have to pass an array of separated strings like this:

```
CSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
  csv << %w(user_name course_code completion_date completion_status score)
  @completes.each do |quiz|
    csv << [member.id.to_s, apply_course_code(@section), quiz.updated_at.strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d'), 'complete', '100']
  end  
end
```